# Azure build project missing in code coverage

Tags: c#, azure-devops, code-coverage, xunit

I have a build for xunit test. the build work, all test pass.

But my code coverage file does not contain my master projects. I try with an empty runsettings file, I got a lot of none important dll/project, but I got some important project missing.

Locally with visual studio 2019, I got no problem. (with my custom runsettings or my empty runsettings)

Its mosly the simpliest projects that are in the zaure codecoverage (like dto's) (and not all of them)

---

all my projects are in .net framework 4.7.2

I use interface for almost every class.

Answer (score 1):

the build server was in release mode but you need pdb file to get codecoverage.
so I add debugType full on the missing dll/projects (on Release platform)

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could Accept it as an Answer , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)